# Trapezoidal rule - calculate accuracy

Tags: calculus, approximation

I'm approximating roots of function using trapezoidal rule, with the number of subdivisions given. However, I want to figure out how accurate my calculation is (on how many decimal points it's accurate). How can I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried/thought of so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: @user12986714 I don't know how to/how to begin.

Comment: Maybe you will want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis) out...